# Pass input date textbox and model item value to controller MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have returned a list of data to a view with ienumerable model person.  Im looking for the user to select one of the rows and display another view passing in the personid from the row selected.  I also want to have 2 input dates from a datepicker at the top of the table to filter the view i want returned.  I want the dates AND row selected personid passed to the controller

My trouble is passing the dates AND personid to the controller.

I need to combine the two ways of getting input dates that can be used for any row selected AND passing the personid of the selected row.

This works for passing the dates AND the personID of the first row.

```
@model IEnumerable<DAL.Person>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExtractDocuments", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div>
    @Html.Label("Date From")
    @Html.TextBox("DateFrom", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ""), new { @class = "datepicker" })
    @Html.Label("Date To")
    @Html.TextBox("DateTo", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ""), new { @class = "datepicker" })
</div>
<br />
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GivenName)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="ExtractDocs">
                    @Html.Hidden("PersonID", item.PersonID)
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
}
```

This works ok for passing any row with the personid

```
@model IEnumerable<DAL.Person>

<div>
    @Html.Label("Date From")
    @Html.TextBox("DateFrom", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ""), new { @class = "datepicker" })
    @Html.Label("Date To")
    @Html.TextBox("DateTo", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ""), new { @class = "datepicker" })
</div>
<br />
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("ExtractDocuments", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GivenName)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="ExtractDocs">
                    @Html.Hidden("PersonID", item.PersonID)
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                 </td>
        </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Not without constructing the link some other way - you can't build it using Razor HTML helpers as you do now, because that runs when the page is built, not after the user has input the data. If you're submitting several fields you'd probably be better off with a small form and a postback anyway, rather than a GET request.

Comment: Any pointers on how to go about that, thanks.

Comment: you know how to make a form, surely? If not, any introductory tutorial will show you

Comment: Yes i can get the dates back in the form but dont know how to get the id (item.PersonID) of the row selected in the list.

Comment: you'd need to put it in a hidden field

Comment: Nice one, got it working.  The dates are as above.  The selected row from the model list is
@Html.HiddenFor(modelitem => item.PersonID). 

Controller is 
public ActionResult GetDataFormCollection forms)

Variables read in using
var id = forms["item.PersonID"]);
var DateFrom = forms["DateFrom"];
var DateTo = forms["DateTo"];

Comment: Actually its not quite right, im getting multiple ids back if there are more than one entry in the person list into var id = forms["item.PersonID"]).  How can I just get the PersonID of the selected row?

Comment: why are you using FormCollection and not a strongly typed ViewModel object? That's not how MVC is supposed to work.

Comment: Anyway, I can't see how you've implemented this, but you should be putting one ID field into each form. Each Person should have its own form so you just submit the data for that person back to the server, just as you would if it had been a hyperlink.

Comment: I was using a strongly typed view model until the need to add dates to filter the subset of data returned after choosing a person.  I've added 2 user input dates at the top of the page and i want those dates along with the id from the view model passed back to the controller.  Maybe i'm going about this the wrong way but it seems like a simple thing to achieve to have user input along with data from a viewmodel passed back.  I am new to MVC as you can probably tell though.

Comment: those two dates can be part of the viewmodel. The view model you send back to the server doesn't need to be the same one which was used to load the page. Perhaps instead of simple form elements you need to use a bit of script to build the form data and post that back programatically.

Comment: Hmm that's intriguing "The view model you send back to the server doesn't need to be the same one which was used to load the page"  Any pointers on how to do this would be much appreciated.  I can't find much on my searches and am kind of hitting a brick wall with this.  Thanks.

Comment: Well you can submit a form to any action method you like. So the viewmodel for the submission will be whatever object that action method is expecting. The fields you use to submit the data simply have to have "name" attributes which match the properties of that viewmodel object

Comment: Ok, got it working with a different model but only the dates come through.  Not really sure how to get the value from the model list item PersonID to pass through.  I don't want to have a From and To Date for every person row, i just want to have a date at the top of the page which can be used for any row they choose.

Comment: I already told you, you need to place it in a hidden field, and the viewmodel you're submitting to needs a person ID. If you want some more specific help you'd be best to edit your question with your new code and new situation / problem (or ask a new question and delete this one, if it's easier). It's hard to know exactly what you've done right or wrong just from a short description. With code, the devil is usually in the detail.

Comment: Edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: I see, thankyou. One thing occurs before I go any further: how many people are likely to be displayed here? Might it be easier just to provide a dropdown list of people for the user to select from, rather than making a whole page full of names laid out as HTML? Then your form would be very straightforward.

Comment: It will typically be a small set of people avg between 5-10.  Not sure a drop down will look as nice as a table.  Ive cut down the code above but there are a few columns in the person view.

Comment: It won't look quite as nice but it'll be a lot simpler to code, and I suspect users will find it fairly intuitive, since they're used to that type of form. I don't have time this evening but tomorrow I should have chance to knock together an answer giving you a couple of options.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.

Comment: Still looking for a solution to this, have you had a chance to look at it yet, thanks.